# How to make my microphone output from my speakers

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, speakers

I'm trying to set up a TeamSpeak 3 music bot for me and my friends on my once Chromebook (that I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on), but I need the audio to be redirected to my microphone so TeamSpeak will pick it up. I've tried using `pavucontrol` via the Recording tab, but it won't redirect the audio correctly - or at least in a way that TeamSpeak can accept it.

Comment: Isn't microphone an input device?

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to take the output and use it as an input essentially